# How to add image or any File to my project in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't add image or any File to my project in NetBeans. When I copy image it's be copied, but when I go to the project and I want paste it. The paste button is inactive as shown in the image:

[image].

I want copy image form Desktop to my project.

These are my tries:

- I tried Ctrl+C then Ctrl+V But it did not work.
- I tried drag-and-drop it.

Comment: Try cntr+V for pasting

Comment: You can't copy a package from one project onto a package in another project, like you appear to be trying in your screenshot. You can drag-and-drop it _into_ (inside of) the other package (if that is really what you are trying to do). Or you can copy/paste the package to the "Source Packages" folder in the target project.

Comment: try checking the file permission on your volume or application.  try install with sudo or admin privs

Comment: I tried all this but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try copying using your windows explorer to your project folder location.